# Send parallel requests and return the first 200 response in rust

Tags: rust, ip, future, lan, reqwest

I am trying to write a discovery function in Rust that discovers the device IP in LAN, this function should sends HTTP requests for all possible IPs in the IP space and once receives 200 status return the value and cancels all others requests (by dropping the future in case reqwest used)

```rs
async fn discover() -> Result<String, ()> {
    for i in 0..256 {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let url = format!("http://192.168.0.{i}:8000/ping");

            reqwest::get(url).await;
        });
    }
}
```

## Edit 1

> once receives 200 status return the value and cancels all others requests

We would like to also validate the response content to make sure that this is the correct device and not someone who is trying to spy on the network we will validate the response by verifying the JWT token returning from the `/ping` endpoint, how can we do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be achievable with the [`futures`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/index.html)-crate and `select_ok()`.

You can do the following:

- convert the range in an `Iterator` and map each element `i` into a *reqwest* request. `select_ok` needs the Futures in the `Vec` to implement `UnPin`; that's why I used `.boxed()` here.
- pass the `Vec` of futures into `select_ok`
- the `response` will contain the first **succesful** future result
- we can use the `remaining_futures` to cancel the remaining requests with `drop` (I am not sure if that works, you need to test this)

```
use futures::{future::select_ok, FutureExt};

async fn discover() {
    let futures = (0..256)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|i| {
            let url = format!("http://192.168.0.{i}:8000/ping");

            return reqwest::get(url).boxed();
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let (response, mut remaining_futures) = select_ok(futures).await.unwrap();

    remaining_futures.iter_mut().for_each(|f| drop(f));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, could you please extending this answer to allow validating the response before accepting it as OK, the /ping endpoint will return a JWT token that I need to validate to make sure that this is the real device and not someone else trying to spy on the network

Comment: @Murad - How would that validation look like?

Comment: I need to get the response content which is JSON containing a JWT, that I need to verify on my end to make sure that the device I pinged is really the device that I want to connect to cause we share the same SECRET KEY

Comment: @Murad - You can put that validation in an `.and_then()` like so: `reqwest::get(url).and_then(|res| { /* ... validation here ... /* ).boxed()`